# UI not aligned on samsung gt i8262

Tags: android-layout, user-interface, android

I have encountered a problem while adjusting UI for various devices on android.

I created res/values-hdpi folder and similar other folders to put the dimensions of the layout there and adjust app's UI. I tested it on two devices

1) [HTC ONE S](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one_s-4574.php)

2) [Samsung GT i8262](http://www.droidgod.com/2014/08/samsung-galaxy-core-duos-gt-i8262-full-specifications-and-features/)

Both the devices comes under normal hdpi category according to android developers site. But the layout is completely misaligned in samsung device. Is there a solution to this sort of problem. I have also checked by changing the dimensions in the values-hdpi folder to confirm that both devices pick from same resource and it does!!! Both pick the dimensions from values-hdpi folder but misaligned in one of them.

Note: Both devices have only hardware buttons no navigation bar. So need not worry about that.

My guess is that HTC ONE S is 256 ppi, samsung gt i8262 is 207 ppi, but both have 4.3" screens, is this the problem?? How do I solve this if this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally created two values folders values-sw360dp-hdpi for HTC 1S and values-sw320dp-hdpi for Samsung GT i8262 and it worked.